# How to dynamically add script tag in HEAD with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I am trying to dynamically add script tag in my angular application. For this a wrote function:

```
var injectSocketIOLib = function (serverAddress) {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = serverAddress + '/socket.io/socket.io.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'false';
    document.head.appendChild(wf);
};
```

The script are injected to head tag, but in console I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

How can I correctly inject script in head ?

EDIT: If I manually add the script to head then I dont get this error and application works correctly

Resolved with this code for script injection:

```
        loadScript = function (src) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var script = $document[0].createElement('script');
            script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    deferred.resolve(e);
                });
            };
            script.onerror = function (e) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    deferred.reject(e);
                });
            };
            script.src = src;
            $document[0].body.appendChild(script);
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

To inject script need to call this:

```
loadScript('https://mysite.com/someplugin.js').then(function() {
    // Script loaded succesfully.
    // We can now start using the functions from someplugin.js
}).catch(function() {
    // There was some error loading the script. Meh
});
```

Comment: When your page finishes loading, are you able to see `socket.io.js` in your network inspector?

Comment: Consider using RequireJS (http://requirejs.org/) ?